# google maps api v3 how do i change the street view position after the page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have a Google Street View iFrame and I'm trying to change the position of the Street View the the address the user puts in.

```
<iframe id="_iframe"
width="400"
height="400"
frameborder="0" style="border:0"
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed /v1/streetview?key=AIzaSyBInT4udbKG9pDGP8Bd6BwUL5M5mG2EHTM&location=46.414382,10.013988&heading=210&pitch=10&fov=35">
```

```
function showPanorama() {
    var iframejs = document.getElementByID('_iframe');
    position: "https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/streetview?key=AIzaSyBInT4udbKG9pDGP8Bd6BwUL5M5mG2EHTM&location=" + marker.position.latLng + "heading=210&pitch=10&fov=35",
    console.log("position changed");
};
```

Comment: What results are you getting from your code ?

Comment: The street view dosnt change. it stays at the location it is originally given.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I clarified the question a bit and fixed the syntax formatting. I hope that helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `"heading=210&pitch=10&fov=35"` that was in your JS. You might need to fiddle with it so good luck!

Comment: I'm not worried about the heading and pitch, its the location i need to change

Comment: Ok. Give me the location you want so i can look into it further. Thanks!

Comment: the location is in a variable that gets the coordinates from a marker on the map. 37N 95W.

Comment: location=46.414382,10.013988 is the variable in the embed code. thats where you use cords and plug it in there.